# How to list all matching lines using apache lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I have requirement to get matching lines across multiple files based on given string.

For example, I have set of log files which contains '|' separated logs. Based on first or second string of each line, and need to collect all such lines to make other operations.

File1.txt

```
abc|123|some string1
abc|123|some string2
abc|123|some string3
xyz|123|some string1
```

File2.txt

```
abc|456|some string3
abc|456|some string2
xyz|345|some string1
xyz|123|some string2
```

I need to collect all lines starting with 'xyz' from files File1.txt and File2.txt as below as result

```
xyz|123|some string1
xyz|345|some string1
xyz|123|some string2
```

Based on the resulting data, I have perform some other operation.

I am trying to explore Apache Lucene for achieving this. I am able to get matching files(documents) which has search data, but I need matching lines.

Comment: How are you storing the documents? I assume storing each line as document will solve your problem.

Comment: Try to use some specific field with respect to the line whom you want to fetch.

Comment: Let me try. Thx.